# How to do an Except filter in Excel as a set operation?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say I have two sets:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

and

```
3
6
```

I want to be able to get the first one except the second, e.g. 1
2
4
5.

How could I do that?

Comment: are those sets in columns? You can e.g. get a helper column to check whether numbe is included in second set and filter in that helper column.

Comment: [so] duplicates: [How can we perform common set operations (union, intersection, minus) in MS Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31186547), [What is the most efficent way to get a Range "set difference" in Excel Automation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/596914)

Comment: [Finding the complements between the two data sets](http://www.msofficeforums.com/excel/1989-finding-complements-between-two-data-sets.html)

Comment: You can use the Advanced Filter

Comment: @RonRosenfeld how?

Comment: You would set up to use a Formula as a criteria.  That's outlined in HELP for the Advanced Filter.  And just use a formula that evaluates to TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the entry in the Set is also in the Exclude list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated by a few people, you can use an advanced filter option. See below as an example of how to set up multiple rules:

[image]l

**Using a helper column:**

[image]

Comment: **(+1)**  just for the animation.

Comment: I think he has posted just a sample dataset, how he can exclude more than  3 values? How it will be automatically updated based on the second range?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Same thing would work if you had a helper column.

Comment: Updated to show both ways.

Answer (score 0):

To use the **Advanced** filter, a formula one could use might be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--AND(A8<>{3,6}))>0
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--AND(A8<>Exclude))>0
```

where `Exclude` is a Name'd range that includes all of the members to be excluded.

[image]

Note that with the Advanced Filter, you can elect to copy the results to another location, or filter the list in place.  And if you use a range instead of an array constant in the formula, the set to be excluded can have any number of members.

Answer (score 0):

-Suppose set 1 and 2 are on columns A and B

-Add header row as first row

-Add this formula in C2 '=VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$1000,1,FALSE)' and fill out on all rows of C column (works for 1000 values)

-Set filter on first row via Menu/Home/Sort&Filter and select only #N/A values in third column

-Now the first column will only contain values not found in the second column